# PHP - Replace child node in XML

Tags: php, xml, appendchild, addchild

I want to replace a child node name in the XML through PHP and also want to append the text in the child node as well. Can you please help me to replace the child node name and append text in the same node in PHP?

## PHP Code:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load('abc.xml');
$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
// Need a code to replace the name of child node "<id>" to "<link>" and append text "abc.com/" in the node <id>
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$result1 = $doc->saveXML(); 
$doc->save('abc.xml');
```

## XML (Current):

```
<rss>
    <data>
        <item>
            <id>1122</id>
            <title>Test 123</title>
        </item>
    </data>
</rss>
```

## XML (Needed):

```
<rss>
    <data>
        <item>
            <link>abc.com/?qs=1122</link>
            <title>Test 123</title>
        </item>
    </data>
</rss>
```

Comment: Try https://www.sitepoint.com/php-dom-working-with-xml/

Comment: This link may help you http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.replacechild.php